# Add event on multiple attendee calendars in one go using google calendar event API

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is it possible to add events on multiple attendee calendars in one go using [Google's calendar event API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/import)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Events: import](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/import)
>
> Imports **an** event. This operation is used to add a private copy of **an** existing event to a calendar.

the key word here is `an` meaning one or single. Most calls in Google apis are done on a single object rather than more that one object.

You may want to check out [batch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch) method.  Note: batching method saves bandwidth not api calls or quota usage.

Comment: I am using https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/import event is not being added to the attendee calendar? Any help or clarification is appreciated.

Comment: That is a different question you may want to take your code and open a new question related to that.  However If its not being added and your not getting an error i would suggest you ensure that you have the correct calendar id its probably being added to a different calendar then the one you are checking.